# SQL server: alter column from nvarchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server

This table has filedate(nvarchar) and Filename. The format needs to be in MMDDYYYY for the filedate.

[image]
I used

```
 replace(cast(filedate as varchar),'-','')
```

and changed the datatype to int, which worked, but not in the format that I need.
[image]

Do I need to update the Fname and then try this or is there another way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *"This table has filedate(nvarchar) and Filename. The format needs to be in MMDDYYYY for the filedate."* There's your problem, store dates as a date and time value, *not* a `varchar`. Fix your design, fix the problem. If you need dates in a specific format, then that's a task for your presentation layer or ETL process. According to your data, a file created on `'12-22-2020'` was created **before** one created on `'9-7-2012'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any column that is expected to have leading zeros is **not** a number.  So, you want a string.  My recommendation is to convert the value to a date and then format it in the way you want:

```
select format(convert(date, '4-17-2020', 110), 'MMddyyyy')
```

Or, better yet, simply convert the value to date.  It is a date.  So you should store and retrieve it as a date.